# Android device screen capture DDMS red tint in eclipse

Tags: android, screen-capture

I can take device screen captures with the DDMS function in Eclipse. Screen capturing is working fine but the image always has a red tint.
It looks like this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/deviceredtint.png/

The device I'm capturing is a Sony Ericsson Xperia with Android 2.3.2.

Does anyone know what I can do that the screened picture hasn't this red tint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Xperia Phone do you have?

This was one of the bugs in the old drivers. You need to update the drivers on the computer.

You can find latest drivers for Xperia Phones here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/driver

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've Sony Ericsson Xperia LT15i.
I'm using Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.6.8. Are there any drivers for Mac OSX too or should they be served from Apple?

Comment: You basically don't need drivers for MAC. Try updating the phone software. LT15 is Xperia Arc, it must have received an update after 2.3.2. http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html